# Datetime conversion error for 1 sql server, but not another

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, date-format, date-conversion

I've got 2 servers running SQL Server 2008, and I have the following query:

```
SELECT cast('13/1/2011' as datetime)
```

If I execute this query on **Server A** I get the result:

```
2011-01-13 00:00:00.000
```

However, if I execute this on **Server B** I get the result:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

I believe this to be a UK/US date format issue as I don't get an error with `12/1/2011` but it does return `2011-12-01 00:00:00.000`

How can I get **Server B** to get the same result as **Server A**? What setting needs to be changed and where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the language setting of the `login` that controls how these ambiguous date formats are interpreted (though this can be overridden with an explicit `SET DATEFORMAT` statement).

The `DEFAULT_LANGUAGE` can be changed via [`ALTER LOGIN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx)

Comment: Where is this changed? I just tried changing a setting for my SQL Server Login from `English` to `British English` but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @Curt - Try opening up a new connection after making that change.

Comment: Is using `ALTER LOGIN` the same as going to SSMS > Security > Login > Properties, and changing the language there? If so, I've tried this with no luck.

Comment: @Curt - Did you open a new connection? `SELECT cast('13/1/2011' as datetime)` Works for me with the same change from `English` to `British English`. Didn't affect previously opened connection using that login though.

Answer (score 1):

Even better, don't rely on the `SET DATEFORMAT` or `DEFAULT_LANGUAGE` settings to ensure your date conversions work as expected. In SQL Server one should always—as a matter of best practice—either use a neutral format, or use an explicit format specifier, no matter what language settings are in use or what your dates look like. Try the following on both servers and you will have no problem.

- Date neutral format: `Convert(datetime, '20110113')`
- Date neutral format: `Convert(datetime, '2011-01-13T00:00:00')`
- Explicit format specifier: `Convert(datetime, '13/1/2011', 103)` - see [SQL Server Books Online: Cast and Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for details.