# Datetime conversion error when deploying a SQL script through NANT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, nant

Right, this is winding me up and has baffled the finest minds in our organisation, so I thought I'd put it to the community here.

He have a NANT build script which performs a build of a local development environment. This includes file copying dll registering and (SQL Server 2000) database building.

The problem I am getting with the database build section.

The database build is seemingly working on every workstation on which it is run, except for one.

The NANT build script files off a number of scripts:

1. Drop existing database
2. Create new database
3. Create logins/users
4. Add core tables and data
5. Add programatic entities.

These are standard TSQL statements which can  be provided, but I'm omitting them presently due to their size.

When completing step 3 and moving onto step 4 it reports the following error:

```
[sql] 6 records affected
[echo] Loading core data...
[sql] Changed database context to 'OurDatabase'.
[sql] SQL Error: The statement has been terminated.
[sql] The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.
[sql] Statement: USE OurDatabase
[sql] -- data inserts for table OurTable
[sql] INSERT INTO OurTable(Field1, Field2) VALUES ('Val1', 'Val2')
....
```

Here is a the nant build step that is casing the problem:

```
<sql  connstring="${sql.connectionstring}"
      transaction="false"
      delimiter="GO"
      delimstyle="Line"
      batch="false"
      print="false"
      source="${svn.temp.directory}sql\isapi\coredata.sql"
      verbose="false" />
```

The SQL script itself starts like:

```
USE ISAPI_Security

-- data inserts for table AE_AuditType
INSERT INTO OurTable(Field1, Field2) VALUES ('Val1', 'Val2')
....
```

Later on there are some date/time fields that are populated, however when the SQL Scripts are run manually there are no reported errors.

What baffles me is that the error message above seems to imply that the datetime conversion error is occuring on the execution of the `use OurDatabase` statement, which stuck me as hihgly implausible.

Does anyone have any explanation of this in any way?

Comment: Check the default language used by the login from that workstation.

Comment: @Martin Smith: Thanks can you elaborate a little?

Comment: Presumably somewhere in the script you have a `datetime` literal in an ambiguous date format. How this is interpreted (e.g. dmy or mdy) will depend on the language of the login. e.g. US English vs British English. Similar to [this recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8053901/73226)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin's suggestion in the comments to my question resolved the issue

The default language was set to 'British English' when I just needed 'English'. I was able to configure this by accessing the user properties through management studio.